# Loop to check where condition from one table to other

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables brand and generic_Drugs. One generic_Drugs model can have many brands model. Therefore, generic_Drugs ids are stored in brands model. However when a generic drug is deleted its id still exists in brands model - this is how my application behaves according to user requirements.

I need a technique to retrieve brands items from database where it only retrieves those brand items whose generic_drug ids exists in generic_drug class table.

Example:

Brand model - brands table

```
    +--------+-----------+
    | id     |Generic id |    
    +--------+-----------+
    |      1 | 2001      | 
    |      2 | 2001      | 
    |      3 | 2002      | 
    |      4 | 2003      | 
    |      5 | 2004      | 
    |      6 | 2004      |
    |      7 | 2005      |
    |      8 | 2006      | 
    |      9 | 2006      | 
    +--------+-----------+
```

Generic_Drugs - genericDrugs table

```
    +-----------+
    | id        |    
    +-----------+
    | 2001      | 
    | 2002      | 
    | 2003      |
    | 2005      |
    +-----------+
```

So I need a technique to list all brand items from brands using where condition applied in generic_drug id in brands table and list only those brands whose generic id exists in generic_drugs table:

Therefore when I run the query it should retrieve only:

```
    +--------+-----------+
    | id     |Generic id |    
    +--------+-----------+
    |      1 | 2001      | 
    |      2 | 2001      | 
    |      3 | 2002      | 
    |      4 | 2003      | 
    |      5 | 2004      | 
    |      7 | 2005      |
    +--------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the same in two ways. One is by using `INNER JOIN`

```
 SELECT Id
 FROM Brand b
 INNER JOIN generic_Drugs gd ON gd.id=b.`Generic id`
```

**OR**

And the other one is by using `EXISTS`

```
SELECT Id
FROM Brand b
WHERE EXISTS( SELECT 1
              FROM generic_Drugs 
              WHERE b.`Generic id`=id )
```

If a brand can't exist without a generic drug, then I would suggest you delete the corresponding brands when you are deleting the generic drug.So that you don't have to make an adjustment in the select query. You can add `Generic id` of the brand table as the `FK` and then delete the corresponding brand records.

Answer (score 0):

We can just use an INNER JOIN.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(b.id) 
FROM brands b INNER JOIN genericDrugs gd
ON b.`Generic id` = gd.id
```

Only the matching records will be retrieved.